# ros tutorials steps

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am learning ros through the steps given in the tutroials the problem i am facing is that when i type
$ roscore
"
... logging to ~/.ros/log/9cf88ce4-b14d-11df-8a75-00251148e8cf/roslaunch-bvo-13039.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://bvo:33919/
ros_comm version 1.4.7

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosversion
- /rosdistro

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13054]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://bvo:11311/

setting /run_id to 9cf88ce4-b14d-11df-8a75-00251148e8cf
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13067]
started core service [/rosout]"
the answer is similar like this but when i type $ rosnode list
on other terminal it gives me an error that no command found what is the problem???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27923/ros-tutorials-steps/) by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What version of ros are you using? When I start roscore, I have ros_comm 1.6.5 which is newer than your 1.4.7. Try upgrading to a current version. Also, what operating system are you using?

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on 2012-02-19**:
i have ubuntu 10.04 lts ros electric mine is also 1.6.5 .but when i run rosnode list it gives me an error no command found.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-19**:
try "rosmake rosnode" and once that is done compiling, run "roscore" in one terminal and try "rosnode list" in another termial. You should see it then.